# Slower training after transfer learning

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorflow, keras, transfer-learning

Before I used a model to categorize cars, bikes and bicycles that looked like this:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 200, 200, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 198, 198, 16)      448       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 99, 99, 16)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 97, 97, 32)        4640      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 48, 48, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 46, 46, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 23, 23, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 33856)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 256)               8667392   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 3)                 771       
=================================================================
Total params: 8,691,747
Trainable params: 8,691,747
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

And now I updated it using VGG16 and replacing the prediction layer with a new FC layer:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 224, 224, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      1792      
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      36928     
_________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 112, 112, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 112, 112, 128)     73856     
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 112, 112, 128)     147584    
_________________________________________________________________
block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 56, 56, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       295168    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 28, 28, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 14, 14, 512)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 7, 7, 512)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 25088)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
fc1 (Dense)                  (None, 4096)              102764544 
_________________________________________________________________
fc2 (Dense)                  (None, 4096)              16781312  
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 3)                 12291     
=================================================================
Total params: 134,272,835
Trainable params: 12,291
Non-trainable params: 134,260,544
_________________________________________________________________
```

Note that the trainable parameters were 8_691_747 without transfer learning and 12_291 with transfer learning. However, training an epoch with exactly the same generators takes way longer with transfer learning (718 vs 65 seconds). Why is that? Am I doing something wrong? Do the Non-Trainable params have a big impact? Isn't it supposed to only have to train one FC layer instead of the whole model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you only backpropagate through the last layer, you still have to complete the entire forward pass of the VGG network.

> Do the Non-Trainable params have a big impact?

There is almost *no* relationship between the number of parameters in a network and the amount of operations needed to compute it's output. So in general, the number of parameters, trainable or not, is not a good indication of how long it will take to run the network.